# If $b\geq l$ with $b,l>1$ then $\exists c>0: l\geq cb$?

Tags: analysis, elementary-number-theory, self-learning

Let $T>1$ be a real number and $a_1$ be the least common multiple of the positive integers $a_0$ and $a$ with $a,a_0>1$ and $T>a_1$. How to show that there exists a positive constant $c$ such that
$$\left \lfloor{T/a_1}\right \rfloor\geq c T/a \ ?$$

This result seems to be obvious. I know that 
$$T/a\geq\left \lfloor{T/a_1}\right \rfloor>T/a-1$$
and obviously if $\left\lfloor{T/a_1}\right \rfloor> T/a-1$ then there is a real number between them, which could be written as $c T/a $. I don't know how to show that though.

Comment: This is not true, $a_1$ can be more than $T$.

Comment: I will add the condition $T>a_1$

Comment: If $T> a_1$ then $\frac T{a_1}> 1$ and $\lfloor \frac T{a_1} \rfloor \ge 1$. so if you let $c =\frac aT$ then $c\frac Ta = 1 \le  \lfloor \frac T{a_1} \rfloor $.

Comment: "then there is a real number between them, which could be written as cT/a. I don't know how to show that though."  Well.  $[T/a_1] > \frac {[T/a_1] +(\frac Ta-1)}{2}> \frac Ta-1$ so if we let $c =\frac {[T/a_1] +(\frac Ta-1)}{2}\div \frac Ta$ that will do it.... but Martund has a simpler idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say:  "then there is a real number between them,($\lfloor \frac T{a_1}\rfloor$ and $\frac Ta - 1$) which could be written as cT/a. I don't know how to show that though."

If we continue that thought:

$\lfloor \frac T{a_1}\rfloor > \frac {\lfloor \frac T{a_1}\rfloor +(\frac Ta-1)}{2}> \frac Ta-1$ so if we let $c =\frac {\lfloor \frac T{a_1}\rfloor +(\frac Ta-1)}{2}\div \frac Ta=\frac {a[\lfloor \frac T{a_1}\rfloor +(\frac Ta-1)]}{2T}$ that will do it.... but Martund has a simpler idea.

.....

If $T > a_1$ then $\frac T{a_1} > 1$ and $\lfloor \frac T{a_1}\rfloor \ge 1 = \frac aT \cdot \frac Ta$.

So ... give a peak at Martund's answer.

"$c = \frac aT$ does the job."

.......

Of course you can choose *any* $c; 0< c \le \frac aT$ and if you choose $c < \frac aT$ we have $c\frac Ta < 1 \le \lfloor \frac T{a_1}\rfloor$ an even stronger result.

Unless of course, we don't know that there are any $c; 0< c < \frac aT$.... which is the Archemedian principal.  Which is what we are trying to prove. I guess.

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer, specially for the first comment which looks simpler to me. Actually, I was reading an article, and in one of the proofs, the inequality in question appeared. I thought that was very intuitive but figure out I didn't know how to show that. You just did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$$c=\frac{a}{T}$$
does the job.